# Defining elements of matrix as a function of two variables (the position $(i,j)$ )

Tags: matrix, image-processing, data, sorting, scripting

I have the following array, which generated from grayscale image data,:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 162 & 162 & 162 & 161 & 162 & 157 & 163 & 161 \\
 162 & 162 & 162 & 161 & 162 & 157 & 163 & 161 \\
 162 & 162 & 162 & 161 & 162 & 157 & 163 & 161 \\
 162 & 162 & 162 & 161 & 162 & 157 & 163 & 161 \\
 162 & 162 & 162 & 161 & 162 & 157 & 163 & 161 \\
 164 & 164 & 158 & 155 & 161 & 159 & 159 & 160 \\
 160 & 160 & 163 & 158 & 160 & 162 & 159 & 156 \\
 159 & 159 & 155 & 157 & 158 & 159 & 156 & 157 \\
\end{array}
\right) .$$
Now, I want to save it as a Table in its coordinates like $M[i\_,j\_]:= \cdots$ to apply some transformation with it or to call the value of any pixel color by its position $(i,j)$. Please help.

Comment: I am confused. It looks like you already have the data as a matrix. What else to do? Just index it using `data[[i,j]]`. And it is better to post a complete self contained example with plain text code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining such a function might be overkill, but if you must you can try

```
M[i_,j_] := A[[i,j]];
```